# Continuity of piecewise functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

[image: continuity of piecewise worksheet]

Need help with this calculus worksheet. not exactly sure of what to do. I have an idea of how to do it but I don't know if it is right.

Comment: What is your idea ?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Show us what it is you think you ought to do and then we can get into whether you're doing it right.

Comment: for A I just solved for c to find the two sided limit of g(-1) by setting x+3=c*x and setting x=-1 and got g(-1)=-2. I did the same for g(2) by doing c*x=x+2 and plugging in 2 for x giving me g(2)=2. when I get to B I get lost and my best guess would be solving for x+3 and c*x and plugging in -1 for both but I know that's wrong. I really need some guidance here cause I have no idea at all. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a definition of a piecewise function in the form
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}a(x) && \text{if }x\geq 0\\b(x) && \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
or something analogous, for continuous functions $a$ and $b$. If $f$ is continuous, then the limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)$ must agree. In particular, however,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}a(x)$$
since, as we approach $0$ from above, we will always be in the domain in which $f(x)=a(x)$. Similarly,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}b(x)$$
since, for $x$ less than $0$, it holds that $f(x)=b(x)$. Since $a$ and $b$ were assumed to be continuous, this is equivalent to saying that $a(0)=b(0)$.

This can be applied here, by considering, at each "transition" between one piece of the function to the next, whether the functions composing the part to the right and left of the boundary agree at the boundary.

Comment: I don't understand this answer? is this even for my question? If so then I'm lost. If you could explain it simpler that'd be great, and thanks for helping.

Comment: Consider that as $x$ transitions past $-1$, the function $g$ goes from being defined as $x+3$ (when $x$ is lower) to being defined as $cx$ (when $x$ is higher). What I'm saying is that $g$ is only continuous if $cx = x+3$ when $x=-1$ - where $g$ transitions from one definition to the next.

Comment: so c would have to be -2 for the function to be left continuous? then c would have to be 2 for the function to be right continuous? which would mean that the function cant be continuous on all reals because -2 and 2 don't agree? correct me if im wrong and thanks a bunch for helping.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score -1):

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd63d.jpg.           X^3 if x <0.       E^x if x>0

$$
  g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  x^3 & x \le 0 \\
  e^{x} x > 0
\end{cases}
$$